# Rails didn't create any db directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While I'm creating a new rails app, there is no db directory while skipping  active record for using mongodb later, By this command.

```
rails new app-name --skip-active-record
```

where `rails new app-name` created db as expected. And so, `rake db:create` or `rake db:migrate` don't act expectedly. I need to edit `/db/seeds.rb` & i cann't find it.

I tried some post fixing, nothing brings the missing directory. I'm new in rails. Have I missed something? Thanks for cooperating.

Comment: Why would it create the directory? You're skipping the database part during initialization.

Comment: so where is my migrate folder or seeds.rb?

Comment: That goes along with the database. There's no need to create it if you're not going to use it.

Comment: @jhpratt you got my question, but didn't get the point. i want to use mogodb as my db, and can't set it up. and i need to use both seeds and models

Comment: You can set it up. You're _explicitly_ telling rails not to by passing `--skip-active-record`.

Comment: @jhpratt I don't want to set it up as I want mongodb as database.

Comment: @jhpratt thanks for helping. by the way, the answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB does not have a schema so you don't need migrations. Thats kind of the whole point of a schema-less database.

`db/seeds.rb` is just a plain Ruby file thats executed when you run `rake db:seed`*. You can create it by running `$ touch db/seeds.rb`.
There is nothing magical about it.

If you are using Mongoid then everything you need is generated when you run:

```
$ rails g mongoid:config
```

So just relax.

Comment: * the seeds file is loaded when you run other tasks as well such as `db:reset`.

Answer (score 4):

By including `--skip-active-record` in the new command, you are telling Rails to not generate the database files, which is correct if you want to use MongoDB!

Next, you need to remove the sqlite gem from your gemfile and add the MongoDb gem to the gem file.  [Here is the Ruby Gems page for MongoDB](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongodb/versions/2.1.0), just copy the gemfile reference from there and paste it into your gemfile.  You always need to run the `bundle` command after altering your gemfile

Then you run `rails g mongoid:config`  and rails will generate the `config/mongoid.yml` for you.

Here is an article for reference: https://gorails.com/guides/setting-up-rails-4-with-mongodb-and-mongoid

Comment: can you specify at which command (step) db will create? I configured mongodb (as above) and `config/mongoid.yml ` exist in my project.

Comment: The db is created on the fly when you insert the first document. MongoDB is not like a SQL database so you need to leave your notions at the door.